# Finding characteristic polynomial of a square matrix and how to proving that matrix is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, characteristic-polynomial

Let $A$ be a square matrix of order $n$ such that $|A + I| = |A − 3I| = 0$ and also $\operatorname{rank}(A)= 2$. I need to find characteristic polynomial of $A$ and have prove that $A$ is diagonalizable.

I thought of using the characteristic polynomial equation $|\lambda I - A| = 0$, and for prove that $A$ is diagonalizable using the $P^{-1}AP$ and proving that $A$ is similar to diagonal matrix
The rank information gives me that there is only $2$ linearly independent rows, so if I use Gauss–Jordan elimination it will remain only $2$ rows that are not zeroes.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I assume he means diagonalizable.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I apologize for the mistake. I edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n$ be the size of your square matrix, and $a,b$ be the respective dimensions of the eigenspaces corresponding to the eigenvalues $-1$ and $3$. Then,
$$a,b\ge1\quad\text{and}\quad a+b\le\operatorname{rank}(A)=2$$
hence
$$a=b=1.$$
Since moreover $\dim\ker A=n-2,$ $A$ is similar to $\operatorname{diag}(-1,3,0,0,\dots,0)$ and its characteristic polynomial is $(X+1)(X-3)X^{n-2}$.

Comment: So from this equation |A + I| = |A − 3I| = 0 we find that our eigenvalues are -1 and 3?

Comment: We only find that $-1$ and $3$ are eigenvalues. There might be more *a priori.* Actually, we find later that $0$ is a third (and last) eigenvalue if $n>2$.

Comment: Oh okay , thank you for your answer! Appreciate it very much!